# Is the cone $\Sigma(T)$ orthogonal to the singular support of a distribution?

Tags: micro-local-analysis, singular-support

Hello I am totally new to microlocal analysis and I have a question. Is the cone $\Sigma(T)$ orthogonal to the singular support of a distribution?
$$\xi \notin \Sigma(T) \iff \exists V\ conic\  neighbourhood\ of\ \xi;\ \forall \eta \in V, \  \forall N,\ |\widehat{T}(\eta)|\le C_N (1+|\eta|)^{-n}$$